# MySQLのAUTO INCREMENTについて

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpmyadminからmysqlの auto incrementを設定したのですが、

## 167 - Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1というエラーが出てデータを追加できません。

idは
データ型:INT, 長さ/値:11, Adjust privileges:チェックあり, A_I:チェックあり
となっています。

このエラーはidが11桁で設定されているが、その範囲以外の値が入れられようとしている、という意味だと思うのですが、auto incrementの値が一体いくつから始まるのか、どこで設定できるのか、などよくわかりません。

分かる方教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

phpmyadmin からの調べ方はわかりませんが、`SHOW CREATE TABLE テーブル名` というクエリを実行すると表示されます。

変更するには `ALTER TABLE テーブル名 AUTO_INCREMENT=999` のようにします。

Answer (score 0):

> auto increment
>   テーブルを選択＞上部メニューの操作(表示や構造が並んでいるところです)
>   のところにあります。
>   また、同箇所で設定することも可能です。